# Get class as a generic parameter and make constraints to it

Tags: generics, typescript, typing

I'm trying to write typing for react-redux (see https://github.com/andrew-w-ross/typings-react-redux/blob/master/react-redux.d.ts)

So I want to say, that `connect` function returns a function with signature `(class: T) => T` where `T` is a `typeof TElement` where `TElement extends React.Component<IAppProps & IDispatcher, void>` (`IDispatcher` just contains dispatch method).